# How to add a new field to html form without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm making a form for my site and basically I want to add a new field to the form if the user click on **+** icon.

Here's the code:

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Product Image 1:</label>
        <input type='file' name='product_img1' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Product Image 2:</label>
        <input type='file' name='product_img2' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Product Image 3:</label>
        <input type='file' name='product_img3' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Add more images: <a href='' title='click this icon in order to add more images'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></a></p>
```

So if user click on this little *plus sing*, another field should be added to the form without refreshing the page. So the code will be this:

```
<div class='form-group'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label>Product Image 1:</label>
            <input type='file' name='product_img1' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label>Product Image 2:</label>
            <input type='file' name='product_img2' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label>Product Image 3:</label>
            <input type='file' name='product_img3' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label>Product Image 4:</label>
            <input type='file' name='product_img1' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>Add more images: <a href='' title='click this icon in order to add more images'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></a></p>
```

So because I'm not familiar with jQuery stuff, I asked this question here, hopefully someone helped me with that. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked cloning in jquery? Get your fishes yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read jQuery [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#clone-field').clone().appendTo('#form');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="form">
  <div id="clone-field">
    <input type='file' name='product_img[]'>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<button id="add">Add more images</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden field that will count the current total fields. Then use the jquery APPEND function. see below:

```js
$("#addbtn").click(function(){
  var next = parseInt($('#counter').val()) + 1;
  $("#group1").append("<div class='form-group'><div class='form-group'><label>Product Image "+next+":</label><input type='file' name='product_img"+next+"' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'></div></div>");
  $('#counter').val(next);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="group1">

 <div class='form-group'>
     <div class='form-group'>
         <label>Product Image 1:</label>
         <input type='file' name='product_img1' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class='form-group'>
     <div class='form-group'>
         <label>Product Image 2:</label>
         <input type='file' name='product_img2' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class='form-group'>
     <div class='form-group'>
         <label>Product Image 3:</label>
         <input type='file' name='product_img3' class='form-control my-colorpicker1'>
     </div>
 </div>

</div>
<input type="hidden" name="counter" id="counter" value="3">
<p>Add more images: <a href='#' title='click this icon in order to add more images' id="addbtn">test<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the jQuery documentation. Or you should probably see some jQuery tutorial.

In any case, since I know that jQuery can be intimidating at first, here is an updated version that does what you want to achieve: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/KZaxdG.

Basically I added the jQuery library and this code snippet:

```
$('#extra-q').hide(0); //Hide the extra question

$('#add-more').off().on('click', function() { //Set the plus button click trigger
  $('#extra-q').show(0); //Show the extra question
})
```

Note that this does not append a new element, it only shows a hidden element. I think it is better to do so, this way your code in your backend will be easier.